# Remove duplicate axis labels when using coord_flip with geom_boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How remove the second axis labels (red box) of the next figure:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(
    x = factor(gear, labels = c("level 1", "level 2", "level 3")), y = hp)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar") +
    xlab("Levels") +
    stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point", shape = 21, size = 2, 
                 color = "black", fill = "gray90") +
    facet_wrap(~vs, scales = "free", ncol = 2) +
    coord_flip() +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `facet_grid()` in place of `facet_wrap()`, where the default layout tries to combine axes where possible (and won't duplicate your axis in this example):

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(
  x = factor(gear, labels = c("level 1", "level 2", "level 3")), y = hp)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar") +
  xlab("Levels") +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point", shape = 21, size = 2, 
               color = "black", fill = "gray90") +
  facet_grid(~vs, scales = "free") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(
    x = factor(gear, labels = c("level 1", "level 2", "level 3")), y = hp)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar") +
    xlab("Levels") +
    stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point", shape = 21, size = 2, 
                 color = "black", fill = "gray90") +
    facet_wrap(~vs, scales = "free_x", ncol = 2) +
    coord_flip() +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]